# How can I add more themes on Elementary-Tweaks?

Tags: applications, themes

I have downloaded elementary-tweaks for Freya. I have also installed a few themes using PPA. What if I have a theme in a file and I want to include it in the gallery of the themes? How can I add it manually without having to use the PPA?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are two ways:

**Copy the theme to the system wide theme folder**

```
sudo cp -R [theme-folder] /usr/share/themes
```

**Copy the theme to your users local theme folder**

```
cp -R [theme-folder] ~/.themes
```

If your local theme folder doesn't exist yet, you will have to create it first:

```
mkdir -p ~/.themes
```

---

It's not recommended to use elementary-tweaks as it has been known to break systems. Instead use this command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "CoolestThemeOnEarth"
```

However, if you want to, you can use elementary Tweaks to do the same thing.

Comment: Your answer is pretty good. I think that you should edit it and state that `elementary-tweaks` is currently unsupported.

Comment: @r3bl thank you for your input, I've updated my answer :)

Comment: @Rafael if `[theme-folder]` and `"CoolestThemeOnEarth"` are supposed to be the same string, then that should be made clear in the answer. If they are not, how are they different and where does one obtain `"CoolestThemeOnEarth"` from?

Comment: There is a new, maintained fork of [`elementary-tweaks`](https://github.com/elementary-tweaks/elementary-tweaks) for Loki, so I'd change the part about it being unmaintained (the queue is already filled with my edits or else I'd do it myself)