# How to change elementary OS themes

Tags: themes

How to change elementary OS Themes ?
Is it possible to add new themes ?

Answer (score 6):

This answer does cover your question about how to change themes:
[How can I add more themes on Elementary-Tweaks?](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/45/how-can-i-add-more-themes-on-elementary-tweaks)?

You can install new themes and themes' usually have their own instructions at their files.

You can see from elementary-tweaks the themes that is installed but it is not recommended since elementary-tweaks is no longer maintained.

Also you can use dconf-editor to change the theme (also developers warns that dconf-editor can show you some options that should not be messed in order to not break the system , dconf is a bit like the registry editor on Windows).

For dconf-editor;

Open terminal and install if you don't have dconf-editor:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Open dconf-editor at terminal:

```
dconf-editor
```

CTRL + F and write gtk-theme, as changing the value of gtk-theme you can change your theme.

Also you can change your window theme with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme "NameOfTheme"
```

Answer (score 2):

An Example:

**[Arc Theme](https://github.com/horst3180/Arc-theme)** have a readme file with a tutorial for install that theme

Comment: Arc Dark is awesome, but interestingly I've run into the gray text problem with it too. So it may not solve the issue.